# How do I schedule a Python script to run in a Linux VM?

Tags: python, virtualization, cron, nohup, azure

I tried using crontab but didn’t work. Also, do I need a nohup to keep it running after exit the SSH connection?

```
02 19 * * * /usr/bin python3.7 myScript.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors there. First, if you want to run `myScript.py` with `python3.7` which is in `/usr/bin`, then you need:

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 myScript.py
```

Next, you need to give the full path to the script. So if the script is in your home directory, use (change `/home/marcelo/` to your actual home directory):

```
02 19 * * * /usr/bin/python3.7 /home/marcelo/myScript.py
```

And no, you don't need `nohup` or anything else. This won't be connected to your ssh session in any way.

Finally, it is more common to use shebangs for this sort of thing. Just add this line as the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
```

Then, make it executable (`chmod +x /home/marcelo/myScript.py`) and you can run your script directly:

```
02 19 * * * /home/marcelo/myScript.py
```

Comment: thank you very much! the error was: my python is installed at `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`